# How to I make this script stay in day and night longer?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, lighting, light

I don't quite understand this code so I am having difficulty modifying it.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SunScript : MonoBehaviour {
    public float duration = 1.0F;
    public Light lt;
    void Start() {
        lt = GetComponent<Light>();
    }
    void Update() {
        float phi = Time.time / duration * 0.1f * Mathf.PI;
        float amplitude = Mathf.Cos(phi) * 0.5F + 0.5F;
        lt.intensity = amplitude;
    }
}
```

This moves the light's intensity up and down in a cycle. However, I would like to have it stay at its brightest and its dimmest for a while before it starts to move back the other direction. How should I do this?

Comment: can`t you just inscrease the duration variable ?

Comment: Find some online math ploter like [this](http://fooplot.com/#W3sidHlwZSI6MCwiZXEiOiJjb3MoeC8xLjAqMC4xKnBpKSowLjUrMC41IiwiY29sb3IiOiIjMDAwMDAwIn0seyJ0eXBlIjoxMDAwLCJ3aW5kb3ciOlsiLTMuNjg3NDk5OTk5OTk5OTk2NCIsIjE2LjYyNDk5OTk5OTk5OTk5IiwiLTYuMDMxMjQ5OTk5OTk5OTk2NCIsIjYuNDY4NzQ5OTk5OTk5OTk2NCJdfV0-) and put your math equation using Time.time as a x parameter. Then modify your equation as you desire.

Comment: @Louis-Roch Tessier I only want to increase the brightest and darkest, not the time in between. Duration controls the entire cycle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about replacing `Mathf.Cos(phi)` one of [these](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/100655/cosine-esque-function-with-flat-peaks-and-valleys) functions instead of just a cosine?

Using the equation at the bottom of that page:

```
float amplitude = Mathf.Sin(Mathf.PI / 2f * Mathf.Cos(phi)) * 0.5f + 0.5f;
```

For the formula with the b term, you could do this (using extra temp variables to make it a little more readable).

```
float b = // whatever your b parameter is or have this declared as a class field that you can set in the Unity editor
float cosine = Mathf.Cos(phi);
float numerator = 1f + (b * b);
float denominator = 1f + (b * b * cosine * cosine);
float amplitude = (Mathf.Sqrt(numerator / denominator) * cosine) * 0.5f + 0.5f;
```

Comment: This will make the transition from day to night / night to day faster.

Comment: That works better than what I had, but the graph above that (the one with all the b^2 stuff) looks better. How would I convert that equation into C# code?

Comment: I added the b equation to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the Unity [AnimationCurve](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AnimationCurve.html) to achieve this:

```
public class SunScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float duration = 1.0F;
    public AnimationCurve curve;

    private Light lt;

    void Start()
    {
        lt = GetComponent<Light>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        lt.intensity = curve.Evaluate((Time.time % duration) / duration);
    }
}
```

Simply make sure your curve is from **0** to **1** following X axis and make it the values you want on the Y axis.

*Hope this helps,*